# ActiveMQ connection refused

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am trying to use `activemq` in my application, but keep getting an error when I try and connect to **localhost**:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:534)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:526)
    at sender.MessageSender.sendMessage(MessageSender.java:16)
    at sender.SenderMain.main(SenderMain.java:13)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:456)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:504)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:467)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.start(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:132)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:273)
    ... 8 more
```

There is a file that should be run to start it up (active mq) and this is a `.bat` file on windows machines. When you run it then it starts and you leave it running in the command prompt.

At home I have a mac and using the **mac equivalent** the terminal just prints:

```
Last login: Mon Oct 29 19:57:15 on ttys000
(null):~ rickilambert$ /Users/rickilambert/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.7.0/bin/macosx/activemq ; exit;
Usage: /Users/rickilambert/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.7.0/bin/macosx/activemq { console | start | stop | restart | status | dump }
logout

[Process completed]
```

Can anyone please help me to get this thing up and running?

Comment: Um, it's telling you exactly what the problem is. `Usage:` isn't a suggestion. `activemq start`

Comment: @BrianRoach I think the OP is presenting the usage from his mac os machine, the issue is on windows.

Comment: @dan - He's trying to start activemq on his mac. He's not doing so and ignoring the message that tells him how. And since he hasn't started it, his application can't connect to it.

Comment: i am a new mac user and much more comfortable with windows so im not sure exactly how it should be started

Comment: @SkyR - Read my first comment. And the `Usage:` message you received when you didn't give it an option. You have to pass `start` to it.

Comment: ok so rather than double clicking the file i need to run it from the command line. ok let me try that

Comment: Heh ... you didn't mention the double-clicking part. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your application is not able to connect to activemq. Check that your activemq is running and listening on localhost 61616.

You can try using: `netstat -a` to check if the activemq process has started. Or try check if you can access your actvemq using admin page: localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp

On mac you will start your activemq using:

```
$ACTMQ_HOME/bin/activemq start
```

Or if your config file (activemq.xml ) if located in another location you can use:

```
$ACTMQ_HOME/bin/activemq start xbean:file:${location_of_your_config_file}
```

In your case the executable is under: `bin/macosx/activemq` so you need to use: `$ACTMQ_HOME/bin/macosx/activemq start`

Comment: sorry to be a royal pain in the ass but i am getting  No such file or directory even though i no the file is there

Comment: @SkyR Just now I noticed that your executable is under: `bin/macosx/activemq`. I updated my answer.

Comment: lol thanks. thats made a slight difference. it suggests its running now but i still get the same exception (null):macosx rickilambert$ ./activemq start
Starting ActiveMQ Broker...

Comment: @SkyR you can check in logs if the server is started. Also you can check if the server is started using the URL that I provided in my answer. Usually it taking a second or two to start, after issuing your  start command.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem when I was using the below to obtain connection factory
  ConnectionFactory factory = new
 `ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://:61616");`

Its resolved when I changed it to the below

`ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://:61616");`

The below then showed that my Q size was increasing..

`http://:8161/admin/queues.jsp`

Comment: ``tcp://:61616`` cause to the error ``Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://:61616. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null``. Without credentials got ``User name [null] or password is invalid``. I have to use correct IP address with username and password here.

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar problem. In my case brokerUrl was not configured properly. So that's way I received following Error:

```
Cause: Error While attempting to add new Connection to the pool: nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL : tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

& I resolved it following way.

```
   ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();

  connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://hostname:61616");
  connectionFactory.setUserName("admin");
  connectionFactory.setPassword("admin");
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works. The reference documentation says this: "If the broker is present, an embedded broker is automatically started and configured (provided no broker URL is specified through configuration)" But you've specified a broker URL, so this would mean that Spring Boot would not launch an embedded broker. Are you using an embedded broker?

Comment: read this document : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html

Comment: In my case I want to run my created Instance. Thats why I provided URL. spring.activemq.broker-url not provided then spring boot instantiate  default one.

Comment: Check 1) Activemq started or not with the following command : netstat -a